# Is it possible to write a code that opens a program and the login is hidden?

Tags: vbscript

First code: To hide the program when it is running.

```vb
Dim WShell
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShell.Run "program name", 0
Set WShell = Nothing
```

Second code: Runs the program and puts an email and logs in.

```vb
Set a = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
a.Run "program name\"
WScript.Sleep (5000) 
a.SendKeys ("email")
a.SendKeys Chr(9)
a.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

I am trying to merge the first code with the second code, but I failed
where I want to run the program and login to it via email automatically hidden.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem clearly, so anyone can reproduce it.

Comment: I want a code to open a program and put my Email in it automatically but hidden from the user

Comment: What do you mean by `put my Email in it`? Do you want to copy email text? Also, what program you are trying to run? Notepad or Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript cannot send keystrokes to hidden windows, meaning what you're asking is not possible in VBScript. It might be possible with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), though, using the [`ControlSend`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) method:

```
Example()

Func Example()
    ; Run Notepad
    Run("notepad.exe")

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the Notepad window to appear.
    Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

    ; Wait for 2 seconds.
    Sleep(2000)

    ; Send a string of text to the edit control of Notepad. The handle returned by WinWait is used for the "title" parameter of ControlSend.
    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "Edit1", "This is some text")

    ; Wait for 2 seconds.
    Sleep(2000)

    ; Close the Notepad window using the handle returned by WinWait.
    WinClose($hWnd)

    ; Now a screen will pop up and ask to save the changes, the classname of the window is called
    ; "#32770" and simulating the "TAB" key to move to the second button in which the "ENTER" is simulated to not "save the file"
    WinWaitActive("[CLASS:#32770]")
    Sleep(500)
    Send("{TAB}{ENTER}")
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: thanks for answer i find this good but stell the from not hide
`code`
 Run("C:\file.exe", "",@SW_HIDE)
 Sleep(5000)
$var = ControlSend('titel', '', '', 'taxt')
$var = ControlSend('titel', '', '', '{ENTER}')
`code`

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with AutoIt, but you probably need to use the handle to the (hidden) window (`$hWnd`) rather than the window title. For further help you may want to post this as a new question.